# entitymanager in entity symfony 6

Tags: symfony6

I need to use entitymanger

app\entity\activity

```
<?php


class Activity
{
 

    public function getActivity(){


        return  $this->entityManager
        ->getRepository(Activity::class)
        ->findAll();
       
    }
}
```

services.yaml

```
services:
    
    App\Entity\Activity: 
        arguments: 
            $entityManager : "@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"
```

But i have this error

> Too few arguments to function App\Entity\Activity::__construct(), 0
> passed in
> C:\laragon\www\lezink\src\Controller\Admin\DashboardController.php on
> line 155 and exactly 1 expected

i have try to pass call in the the service

Comment: Perhaps you have some reasons for this way, but it seems to me that this is not correct.
If your entity requires some data, then a relationship must be established there, for example, MayToOne

Comment: For me this looks a little like Laravel style. The Activity is the entity. Retrieving the Entity is done by a repository.

Answer (score 0):

EntityManagers should never be injected into Entities

The right solution is to make a repository for the Activity entity and define your methods to retrieve Activity entities from the repository

To configure a class to be the repository of an entity you can reference it in the repositoryClass property of the Entity annotation

Check out the official documentation to get started: https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html